# truncate length of contextual lines in git patches

Tags: git, patch, git-diff

Sometimes the unchanged lines displayed in a git patch - the ones given just for context - are very long. Is there an elegant way to limit the character count of those unchanged lines to improve readability?

A silly example: edit the [GNU GPL-3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html). My desired, succinct patch:

```
GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE
Version 3, 29 June 2007
- Copyright © 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc. <https://fsf.org/>
+ Copyright © 2007 Free! Software Foundation, Inc. website: fsf.org
Everyone is permitted to copy and distribute verbat[...]
Preamble
- The GNU General Public License is a free, copyleft license for software and other kinds of works.
+ The GNU General Public License is a free(ky), copyleft(ish) license for software and other kinds of wonky works.
The licenses for most software and other practical [...]
When we speak of free software, we are referring to[...]
```

If you visit the linked doc, you'll see that the contextual (unchanged and therefore truncated) lines would be 100s of characters long.

Changes may happen anywhere in a given line, so changed lines would need to be untruncated.

If my pie-in-the-sky command/flag doesn't already exist and just needs to be invented, it may be something mirroring grep: `git diff --only-matching {2,50}`. I.e. give 2 contextual lines around a changed line (by default git gives 3); limit each contextual line to 50 columns.

Naturally, short lines in every repo would be the ideal, but considering the times you have to work with the repo you get vs the repo you want, suggestions welcomed.

Comment: What is the context where you don’t want to see the surrounding lines, what commands are you issuing? I ask because a patch without the exact lines won’t apply. Please add to the question an example of what you are doing, and seeing

Comment: You may find just piping to `cut` does what you want

Comment: The desired output is most easily generated by a diff post-processor that you configure as a custom pager. An example of such a post-processor is [diff-highlight](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/diff-highlight).

Comment: Diff-highlight looks promising - I'll give it a try. Thanks for your pointers, @j6t!

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you look at the patch on the console using the default pager, `less`. The trick is to convince `less` not to fold lines. You can do that by passing `-S` to less. One option to do that is to set the environment variable `LESS`.

Inspect the variable:

```
echo $LESS
```

Then add `S` to the mix, for example:

```
export LESS=FRS
```

Now `less` tells you whether lines were truncated. Use the left and right arrows to scroll horizontally.

Naturally, this applies to all lines, not just context lines.

Comment: This workaround helps somewhat. You understand the challenge, clearly. :)